# Compare two text same string and only replace behind string

Tags: c#

I have two text files.

I need translate B text. Although I have English version, the English language file is behind.

I can use editor replace function, but the languages file have a hundreds of thousands line and not in sequence.

A text file (English):

```
    AREA_01_OPEN = "Hell is Empty.\All the devils are here."
    AREA_02_INFO = "Cities are asphalt deserts?\No, they are concrete jungles where
    AREA_01_INFO = "Have you ever seen the Devil? It's closer than you think.\In fact, you might already know him!"
```

B text file (Japanese):

```
    AREA_02_INFO = "都会がアスファルトの砂漠だと？\否、弱肉強食のコンクリートジャングルさ！"
    AREA_01_OPEN = "Hell is Empty.\All the devils are here."
    AREA_01_INFO = "悪魔を見た事ありますか？案外近くにいるんですよ。\そう、あなたが知ってるあの人も…"
```

Example of what I need to do：

Check A text and B text are the same key string, for example "AREA_01_INFO".
Will automatically ( behind string in A text ) replace ( behind string in B text ) for example.

Have you ever seen the Devil? It's closer than you think.\In fact, you might already know him! (replace)> 悪魔を見た事ありますか？案外近くにいるんですよ。\そう、あなたが知ってるあの人も…

only replace behind string.

First I check two text string front, if same, will behind string in (a text )replace behind string in B text .

this is example program.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ4JR.png
English string and Japanese string are not in order
but they all have key string. (for example AREA_02_INFO,AREA_01_OPEN,AREA_01_INFO)
i hope compared two text same key and replace english langague behind string to japanese langague behind string

Comment: What is the actual question here? Can you post a [mcve] of what you tried?

Comment: I tried to clean up the grammar, but couldn't really make sense of some phrases. For instance "Will automatic" is somewhat meaningless. If you're using machine translation for your question, you may have issues understanding the answer. Note that we have [ja.so] if you are more comfortable conversing in Japanese.

Comment: sorry , i am from china  , so i english is bad. I have tried to correct the grammar

Comment: Ok, no problem about the English, but how's your C#? Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: sorry , I am just getting started learning c#, I will only now read text content to ram.
I hope to find related functions to achieve , i already upload example program ui image

Answer (score 0):

Try to read both files into memory using the `File` class. Use two `Dictionary<string, string>` so you can access each string for each key. Then simply access the dictionary containing the english strings use the key to get the corresponding japanese string from the japanese dictionary and replace the string in the english dictionary

Comment: Did you mean `Dictionary<string, string>`? Also, what if there are duplicates?

Comment: corrected it. There shouldnt be any duplicates as these are translations of whole sentences

Comment: Duplicate _key_. It's 2 text files, with a ton of entries; hopefully, they all have unique keys, like "AREA_01_INFO", etc - but nothing prevents these files from having _two complete sentences_ assigned to the same key at two different spots.